# mysql datetime range select

Tags: mysql, datetime, cron

I have a recurring payment mode in the system. All is well, API successful response is logged on the database.
The concern of my question is, I'm about to automate the subsequent payment action (which unfortunately, the payment gateway doesn't support) of the system.
Via cron I'll schedule a check on whether which accounts must be included in the subsequent process and notice.
I have here a snip of the database entry:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| payment_date        | payment_expirydate  | transaction_number |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| 2012-02-14 03:47:15 | 2012-05-14 03:47:15 | 1-67815163         |
| 2012-02-16 00:53:03 | 2012-05-16 00:53:03 | 1-69010235         |
| 2012-02-16 08:57:16 | 2012-05-16 08:57:16 | 1-69027483         |
| 2012-02-16 09:08:06 | 2012-05-16 09:08:06 | 1-69027694         |
| 2012-02-16 09:58:17 | 2012-05-16 09:58:17 | 1-69028921         |
| 2012-02-17 09:28:32 | 2012-05-17 09:28:32 | 1-69072076         |
| 2012-02-17 06:17:45 | 2012-05-17 06:17:45 | 1-69068200         |
| 2012-02-17 11:12:08 | 2012-05-17 11:12:08 | 1-69074788         |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

I am having a difficulty in creating the SQL query for this. Assuming, the date today is **2012-05-16** and the time is **07:00:00**. I want to get all the accounts which is today and less than the current time. For instance, the only valid account (based on the current date and time I indicated) I need is account **1-69010235**.

Also, any tips if on what interval should I set my cron to run?

Comment: `select * from table where now() > unix_timestamp(payment_expirydate)`

Comment: how do you feed the list of today's account to the payment action system?

Comment: thanks, but this will return entire accounts before the date. Any idea on returning just the accounts on similar to the current date only?

Comment: @cctan - place the return result in an array then I use parallel curl to request to the API.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your objective? "accounts which is today and less than the current time" is difficult to understand. I'll take a guess and see if I'm close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This query will return all records that expire today -

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts
WHERE payment_expirydate BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND (CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
```

If you want all accounts expiring today but less than current time -

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts
WHERE payment_expirydate BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

For codeigniter's AR implementation you should be able to use -

```
$this->db->where('payment_expirydate BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', NULL, FALSE);
```

Comment: I have added CI AR example to my answer. Hope this works for you. I haven't tried it as I do not use CI.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT group_concat(transaction_number) as transaction_number
FROM tab
WHERE payment_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

You can use this to return a string and use perl to split the string and pass to curl.

sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle).

Comment: I have removed my previous comment now that you have modified your query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the records in the table you show that are valid for the current time - and valid means that the payment_date is earlier than now and payment_expirydate is later than now, you can use:

```
SELECT transaction_number from `table`
WHERE payment_date > now()
AND payment_expirydate < now();
```

Does that get what you want?